# How to convert integer value into a string but with different contents

Tags: java, string, integer, blackjack

Sorry if the question is confusing, but I am making a small blackjack program to test my skills in java thus far, and I've come to a problem that I cannot think of a way out of.

Currently, I have a Card class that create the cards for the game, and I have the random number generator set up to go between integer values 1-14. However, how can I write a method that will take that integer value, and get it to output that if the integer value of 11, a string value will show this card as a jack, and not a 11 card, etc.

Here is all I have at the moment, unfortunately.

```
private void assignCard(){
        for(int i = 0; i < cardInHand.length; i++){
            if(cardInHand[i] >= 11){

            }
        }
    }
```

The point of the method I have here is to run through the contents of the cards in the players hand, and check to see if they're above 11, and as such would then begin the process of sorting out which number corresponds to the the proper card type (jack, queen, etc) in a string value printed to the user.

In saying all this, I am still only a beginner at programming, so there is a chance that this project may be out of my skill level, but any sort of relevant suggestions/criticism are greatly appreciated.

Comment: No idea what you are looking for, A method like `String cardname(int cardId)` ? That is pretty simple. If you can't do that (just a couple of `if` statements) then you are probably out of your depth.

Comment: what you should really do is if your Card class has an integer representation you should have a method or even better, a variable, that is the string representation of that card's value

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz that was the idea I had in mind...perhaps the wording of my question is poor. How would you go about implementing that?

Answer (score 2):

Keep the "names" of the cards in a String array like

```
    int cardNum = 11;
    String [] cards = new String [] {"ace", "two", "three", ..., "jack", "queen", "king"};

    System.out.println(cards[11 - 1]);
```

As solution like this allows you to internationalize the card names later

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking for but assuming you want to take in array of ints and print out the name of the cards this should do it.

```
private static void assignCard(int[] cardInHand){
    for(int i = 0; i < cardInHand.length; i++){
        if(cardInHand[i] == 11){
            System.out.println("Jack");
        }
        if(cardInHand[i] == 12){
            System.out.println("Queen");
        }
        if(cardInHand[i] == 13){
            System.out.println("King");
        }
        if(cardInHand[i] == 1 ){
            System.out.println("Ace");
        }
        if(cardInHand[i] > 2 && cardInHand[i] < 11){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where I come from `1` is called the `ace`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Class called Card where we create a mapper for each card. Notice that is just use 0 for joker but in the for loop I start at 1 to not include it as shown in the output. hope this helps!

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Card {
    public int cardV;
    public String cardS;
    private HashMap<Integer, String> cardMapper;

    Card(int newCardValue){
        //create our mapper first
        cardMapper = createCardMapping();

        cardV = newCardValue;
        //once the mapper is created we can now figure out the string of our card
        cardS = FindCardStringRep(cardV);

    }

    private String FindCardStringRep(int key)
    {
        String cardString = "Card Doesn't Exist";

        if(cardMapper.containsKey(key))
        {
            cardString = cardMapper.get(key);
        }

        return cardString;
    }

    public HashMap<Integer, String> createCardMapping()
    {
        HashMap<Integer, String> mapper = new HashMap<>();
        String[] cardNames = {"joker", "ace", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", 
                            "eight", "nine", "ten", "jack", "queen", "king"};

        //go through and create a mapping of the indices of cardNames to the String representations
        //Note 0 = joker, ace = 1, two = 2 and so on
        //we start at 1 so we ignore the joker anyways
        for(int intVal = 1; intVal < cardNames.length; intVal++)
            mapper.put(intVal, cardNames[intVal]);

        return mapper;
    }

}
```

Then in a main method you could something like the following

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    Card card = new Card(i);

    System.out.println("Card " + card.cardV + " is a " + card.cardS);
}
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Card 0 is a Card Doesn't Exist
Card 1 is a ace
Card 2 is a two
Card 3 is a three
Card 4 is a four
Card 5 is a five
Card 6 is a six
Card 7 is a seven
Card 8 is a eight
Card 9 is a nine
Card 10 is a ten
Card 11 is a jack
Card 12 is a queen
Card 13 is a king
Card 14 is a Card Doesn't Exist
Card 15 is a Card Doesn't Exist
Card 16 is a Card Doesn't Exist
Card 17 is a Card Doesn't Exist
Card 18 is a Card Doesn't Exist
Card 19 is a Card Doesn't Exist
```